# What is meant by "bash"?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have been using Ubuntu for a short period of time. I have seen the term "bash" in many places, including a terminal. I have still not understood what it is.

Can somebody please explain clearly?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?](http://askubuntu.com/q/506510/295286)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expansion for   [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) is  **Bourne Again shell**.

> Bash is the shell, or command language interpreter, for the GNU
>   operating system. The name is an acronym for the ‘Bourne-Again SHell’,
>   a pun on Stephen Bourne, the author of the direct ancestor of the
>   current Unix shell sh, which appeared in the Seventh Edition Bell Labs
>   Research version of Unix.
>
> Bash is largely compatible with sh and incorporates useful features
>   from the Korn shell ksh and the C shell csh. It is intended to be a
>   conformant implementation of the IEEE POSIX Shell and Tools portion of
>   the IEEE POSIX specification (*IEEE Standard 1003.1*). It offers
>   functional improvements over sh for both interactive and programming
>   use.
>
> While the GNU operating system provides other shells, including a
>   version of csh, Bash is the default shell. Like other GNU software,
>   Bash is quite portable. It currently runs on nearly every version of
>   Unix and a few other operating systems - independently-supported ports
>   exist for MS-DOS, OS/2, and Windows platforms.

[**Source**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#What-is-Bash_003f)

Answer (score 4):

Bash is a command processor, typically run in a text window, allowing the user to type commands which cause actions. Bash can also read commands from a file, called a script. Like all Unix shells, it supports filename wildcarding, piping, here documents, command substitution, variables and control structures for condition-testing and iteration. The keywords, syntax and other basic features of the language were all copied from sh. Other features, e.g., history, were copied from csh and ksh. Bash is a POSIX shell but with a number of extensions.

The name itself is an acronym, a pun and descriptive. As an acronym, it stands for Bourne-again shell, referring to its objective as a free replacement for the Bourne shell. As a pun, it expressed that objective in a phrase that sounds the same as born again, a term for spiritual rebirth. The name is also descriptive of what it did, bashing together the features of sh, csh and ksh.