# What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?

Tags: command-line, console, terminology

What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?

Comment: (1/2) Agent Cool is mostly correct, but the definition of Console he provides is an outdated one, given this topic. His link has the correct information, if you follow it though.

Read the *whole* definition at his link. Console is used loosely to mean a lot of similar things, but most importantly it usually refers to the LOCAL ATTACHED human input and output devices, e.g. keyboard, display, and maybe mouse.

Comment: (2/2) This may seem like a pedantic point, but as a seasoned systemadmin, I will tell you *it is not*. When a system has a problem and appears to be completely crashed/down/offline, you should check the **physical console** of the system to see if it is still functioning, but simply lost network connectivity. This small detail could save or cost you a data, information processing, etc.

Pedantic, yes. But important.

Comment: @0xSheepdog You might want to expand these comments into a full answer (including definitions or explanations for the other terms as well), posted as such. It's not bad for a question to have multiple answers (except perhaps when they convey exactly the same information and in the same way). I'm not sure why the important practice of checking a machine locally actually relies on knowing/calling its physical human interface a console, but there is perhaps an argument that it's important for effective communication with colleagues or using documentation. (You might clarify that in your answer.)

Comment: Due to their close relation (see all the good answers) these terms are at times used synonymously, which is probably what brought you to ask this.

Comment: The first three are more or less synonymous these days in the context of a modern computer OS.  The difference is in their historical origin.  A command line usually refers to the method for constructing a single shell command rather than the shell interface itself.

Comment: @neon, they often go together, so people use one of the terms to refer to the collection.  (i.e. it's usually obvious from context that they mean a terminal window providing an interface to a command line shell).  Console is sometimes used as a synonym for terminal (KDE even has a terminal emulator called Konsole), but as 0xSheepdog points out, it also has another meaning: locally attached human-interaction hardware.

Comment: Minor side-comment: The terms aren't unique to UNIX/Linux/Ubuntu, so their meanings are _influenced_ by the history of automated computing in general. As such, you can run into varying usages from different sources even if the context is just "Ubuntu". Background of a source can make a difference.

Comment: Cross-posted in SuperuserSE: https://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal and https://superuser.com/questions/347430/whats-the-difference-between-a-console-terminal-and-command-line

Comment: See: [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/5355) at Unix&LinuxSE.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Short answer:

- **terminal** = text input/output environment
- **console** = physical terminal
- **shell** = command line interpreter

---

Long answer:

Console and terminal are closely related. Originally, they meant a piece of equipment through which you could interact with a computer: in the early days of unix, that meant a [teleprinter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter)-style device resembling a typewriter, sometimes called a teletypewriter, or “tty” in shorthand. The name “terminal” came from the electronic point of view, and the name “console” from the furniture point of view. Very early in unix history, electronic keyboards and displays became the norm for terminals.

### Terminal

In unix terminology, a **terminal** is a particular kind of [device file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) which implements a number of additional commands ([ioctls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl#Terminals)) beyond read and write. Some terminals are provided by the kernel on behalf of a hardware device, for example with the input coming from the keyboard and the output going to a text mode screen, or with the input and output transmitted over a serial line. Other terminals, sometimes called pseudo-terminals or pseudo-ttys, are provided (through a thin kernel layer) by programs called [**terminal emulators**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator). Some types of terminal emulators include:

- GUI applications running in the [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System): [Xterm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm), Gnome Terminal, Konsole, Terminator, etc.
- [Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnu_screen) and [tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux), which provides a layer of isolation between a program and another terminal
- [Ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_shell), which connects a terminal on one machine with programs on another machine
- [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), for scripting terminal interactions

The word *terminal* can also have a more traditional meaning of a device through which one interacts with a computer, typically with a keyboard and display. For example an X terminal is a kind of [thin client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client), a special-purpose computer whose only purpose is to drive a keyboard, display, mouse and occasionally other human interaction peripherals, with the actual applications running on another, more powerful computer.

### Console

A **console** is generally a terminal in the physical sense that is by some definition the primary terminal directly connected to a machine. The console appears to the operating system as a (kernel-implemented) terminals. On some systems, such as Linux and FreeBSD, the console appears as several terminals (ttys) (special key combinations switch between these terminals); just to confuse matters, the name given to each particular terminal can be “console”, ”virtual console”, ”virtual terminal”, and other variations.

See also [Why is a Virtual Terminal “virtual”, and what/why/where is the “real” Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/14284/1059).

### Command line [interface]

A **command line** is an interface where the user types a command (which is expressed as a sequence of characters — typically a command name followed by some parameters) and presses the <kbd>Return</kbd> key to execute that command.

### Shell

A [**shell**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29) is the primary interface that users see when they log in, whose primary purpose is to start other programs. (I don't know whether the original metaphor is that the shell is the home environment for the user, or that the shell is what other programs are running in.)

In unix circles, **shell** has specialized to mean a [command-line shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29#Text_.28CLI.29_shells), centered around entering the name of the application one wants to start, followed by the names of files or other objects that the application should act on, and pressing the Enter key. Other types of environments (with the notable recent exception of Gnome Shell) usually don't use the word “shell”; for example, window systems involve “[window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager)” and “[desktop environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)”, not a “shell”.

There are many different unix shells. Ubuntu's default shell is [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) (like most other Linux distributions). Popular alternatives include [zsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsh) (which emphasizes power and customizability) and [fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell) (which emphasizes simplicity).

Command-line shells include flow control constructs to combine commands. In addition to typing commands at an interactive prompt, users can write scripts. The most common shells have a common syntax based on the [Bourne_shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell). When discussing “**shell programming**”, the shell is almost always implied to be a Bourne-style shell. Some shells that are often used for scripting but lack advanced interactive features include [the Korn shell (ksh)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell) and many [ash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell) variants. Pretty much any Unix-like system has a Bourne-style shell installed as `/bin/sh`, usually ash, ksh or bash. On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is [Dash](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/), an ash variant (chosen because it is faster and uses less memory than bash).

In unix system administration, a user's **shell** is the program that is invoked when they log in. Normal user accounts have a command-line shell, but users with restricted access may have a [restricted shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell) or some other specific command (e.g. for file-transfer-only accounts).

---

The division of labor between the terminal and the shell is not completely obvious. Here are their main tasks.

- Input: the terminal converts keys into control sequences (e.g. <kbd>Left</kbd> → `\e[D`). The shell converts control sequences into commands (e.g. `\e[D` → `backward-char`).
- Line edition, input history and completion are provided by the shell.

  - The terminal may provide its own line edition, history and completion instead, and only send a line to the shell when it's ready to be executed. The only common terminal that operates in this way is `M-x shell` in Emacs.
- Output: the shell emits instructions such as “display `foo`”, “switch the foreground color to green”, “move the cursor to the next line”, etc. The terminal acts on these instructions.
- The prompt is purely a shell concept.
- The shell never sees the output of the commands it runs (unless redirected). Output history (scrollback) is purely a terminal concept.
- Inter-application copy-paste is provided by the terminal (usually with the mouse or key sequences such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>). The shell may have its own internal copy-paste mechanism as well (e.g. <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>).
- [Job control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control) (launching programs in the background and managing them) is mostly performed by the shell. However, it's the terminal that handles key combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill the foreground job and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend it.

---

<sub>Recycled from [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con/4132#4132)</sub>

Comment: I'd have to disagree with you on terminal being a proper term for a terminal device file, and/or the terminal-handling code in the kernel (tty ioctls, raw/cooked, basic line editting).  terminal = the stuff that handles escape codes, turns keypresses into characters, and draws on a screen (or prints on paper / tape).  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @PeterCordes At this level of detail, there's no distinction. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_390) defines *terminal* as synonymous to *terminal device*, in the sense of a device file. That's the Unix meaning. It does happen to be the stuff than handles escape codes, turns keypresses into characters and draws on a screen (or transmits over the network, or logs to a file, etc.).

Comment: hrm, yeah terminal does get used in that sense, too.  With the assumption that there's a terminal emulator, or a serial port with a terminal appliance connected to it, on one end of the terminal device that the kernel is handling.  The kernel tty handling (in cooked mode) only handles a few control codes (signals on ^c, line editting on ^u / ^? (delete).  I'm trying to draw a line between the tty code and the part of Linux that implements a VT100-like terminal on a graphics card and a USB/ps2/AT keyboard.  You can compile Linux without that, but not without tty.

Comment: There is some symbiosis between the terminal emulator (or real terminal on a serial port), the kernel tty semantics/behaviour, and the shell or other process on the other end of the tty.  I think I just half-convinced myself I'm wrong here:  Consider resizing your xterm.  "I resized my terminal" sounds to me more like it's talking about stty rows N cols M  than just about changing the size of the X11 window.  (although doing that will  make xterm do the proper ioctls on the tty to update the terminal size parameters.)

Comment: @PeterCordes In the kernel configuration, support for terminals can be left out (it's useful for some rare embedded systems where memory is extremely tight); it's controlled by `CONFIG_TTY`. Support for terminal emulators (more properly called pseudo terminals — “terminal emulator” doesn't always include telnetd, screen, expect, …) is controlled by `CONFIG_UNIX98_PTYS`. Support for PC text mode display and keyboard or the like is controlled by `CONFIG_VT`. See [`drivers/tty/Kconfig`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/Kconfig) in the kernel source.

Comment: Oops, I didn't have a recent kernel source lying around. CONFIG_TTY was only added in 2012. Anyway, yeah hopefully that helps anyone trying to wrap their head around what the different pieces of the puzzle are, and how they fit together.

Comment: @Gilles So when we use the `scanf` function in C(which wraps the system call `read`), are we reading from the keyboard, or the device file 'terminal'? If it's the former, why is it that the characters we type in are also *written* to the console?

Comment: @for scanf reads from stdin. If you run the program from a shell running in a terminal without a redirection, this reads from the terminal device. Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work

Comment: Shell isn't CLI, shell can be either CLI or GUI...

Comment: Sorry for asking this in AU, but what is the name of the default shell in the terminal `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe`? Or they're so tightly coupled over there so that there's no need to distinguish?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` are Windows things. You won't find them on Ubuntu. (I think there's a powershell implementation for Linux now, but it's not common to install it.) Both are command line shells. The default terminal on Windows was called [CSRSS on Windows XP](https://superuser.com/q/194211) and I don't know if that's changed on more recent Windows. For Windows questions, this is the wrong place; you can ask on [su].

Answer (score 92):

A visual representation.

### Terminal

Something you can sit down at, and work like a boss.

[image: Terminal]

### Console

Some hardware that does a bunch of stuff.

[image: Console]

Another example of a console, would be a video game console such as a Super Nintendo [where you can play Actraiser]

### Shell

Basically an application for running commands.

[image: Shell][image: Shell]

### Command Line [Interface]

Basically anything you input commands into.

[image: CLI][image: CLI]

Comment: You stole my idea - I was going to give basically the same answer.  So you can have an upvote.  The point being of course that while these terms are mostly synonymous these days, terms like "terminal" and "console" have their origins in older computing concepts.

Comment: Good effort. Simple and easy

Comment: Well done sir. You've taken an existing idea / concepts / pictures, repackaged it, and made the final product x10 better. Are you Steve Jobs, reincarnated?

Comment: @BenKoshy Maybe. Instead of eating fruit, all I eat is raw meat. Maybe that's his atonement.

Answer (score 21):

From the [Linux Information Project](http://www.linfo.org/):

> [Terminal](http://www.linfo.org/terminal_window.html) : Technically , A terminal window, also referred to as a terminal emulator, is a text-only window in a graphical user interface (GUI) that emulates a console.

In Our words A GUI Application , from where we can access an user's console.

> [Console](http://www.linfo.org/console.html): an instrument panel containing the controls for a computer
>
> [Shell](http://www.linfo.org/shell.html) :A shell is a program that provides the traditional, text-only user interface for Linux and other Unix-like operating systems
>
> [Command-Line](http://www.linfo.org/command_line.html) : A command line is the space to the right of the command prompt on an all-text display mode on a computer monitor (usually a CRT or LCD panel) in which a user enters commands and data

Comment: "Terminal" stands for a physical text-only screen. What you say is actually "terminal emulator".

Comment: @RegisteredUser A terminal emulator is a kind of terminal. The word *terminal* isn't limited to physical terminals (the usual word for that is *console*).

Comment: This definition of *command line* is wrong. A command line isn't limited to an all-text display mode.

Comment: @Gilles I have grabbed it from One web-Link. You have mentioned proper answer fine.

Comment: @AgentCool I don't question your ability to copy-paste. I question your choice of source. What you post is your responsibility, whether you wrote it or not.

Answer (score 21):

The answers here seem very good. However they are too dry and technical for my taste so I'll give a take.

**Terminal** is the end of something - where it terminates. For example if you take the subway in some city, the station where you get down is your terminal. Or in an airport the place where people come out when they reach their destination country is considered the terminal. The reason the terminal in the airport is nowadays both the place you get people onboard and the place you get them off the plane is for obvious economic reasons.

A computer's purpose is to get data, do something with it, and spit out the result. Thus the terminal is any device from where you can get the result of the computation (a screen for example). It just happened that in the first computers you usually had the input (keyboard) and output (screen) as a single device. Because of that, nowadays terminals are considered any input/output devices. A mouse, keyboard, screen, camera, they are all terminals.

**Shell** is an OS thing. On a computer you have the kernel which on Ubuntu for example is the Linux part. Now since the kernel is really low-level a shell is provided - a program that let's the user interact with the kernel in an easy way. That's what BASH is for example.

**Console** is (from a dictionary)

> a flat surface that contains the controls for a machine, for a piece
>   of electrical equipment, etc.

That's why in music industry the board with all the knobs, or in a space shuttle the command table, they are all considered consoles. Super Nintendo and PS2 are also called consoles historically since the first such entertainment devices looked like boxes with a bunch of buttons on them.

**Command line** is just an interface - the opposite of GUI. Namely there are two types of interfaces on a computer; CLI (command line interface) and GUI (graphical user interface). The main difference is that the first one gets input from the keyboard while the second gets input from the mouse.

Comment: What do you mean "the opposite of GUI" ?

Comment: With opposite I mean that you have either CLI or GUI. I have clarified now a bit more in the answer.

Comment: thanks for simple analogy. Can I make a statement that CLI is non GUI based terminal ?

Answer (score 20):

The **Shell** is a program which *processes* commands and *returns* output, like Bash in Linux.

A **Terminal** is a program that runs a **Shell**. In the past it was a *physical device* (before terminals were monitors with keyboards, they were *teletypes*) and then its concept was transferred into software, like GNOME Terminal.

So when I open GNOME Terminal, a black window that runs a **Shell** appears so I can run my commands.

A **Console** is a *special sort of terminal*. It was also a *physical device*. For example in Linux we have *virtual consoles*, which we can access by a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F7</kbd>.

**Console** sometimes means the keyboard and monitor *physically* attached to this computer.

Answer (score 13):

These terms often go together, so people use one of the terms to refer to the collection. (i.e. it's usually obvious from context that they mean a terminal window providing an interface to a command line shell).

To keep this from getting to long-winded, I'm just going to say xterm as a stand-in for XTerm / Gnome Terminal / Konsole / mrxvt / etc / etc.  Same for bash.

*Console* has multiple other specific meanings, so leave that out for now.

**Terminal**: Something that provides human interaction with programs through a bidirectional stream of ASCII / UTF8 / other characters, usually with VT100 or similar escape code processing.  (E.g. backspace, delete, arrow keys, etc. generate escape codes.  Programs can print escape codes to move the cursor around the terminal screen, switch to bold text, and/or color, clear or scroll the screen, etc.)  In the old days, this was often a dedicated appliance with a screen and keyboard and a serial port.  Now, it's usually a program like xterm.

There are device files for programs to read/write from/to terminals, and virtual terminals also have the other side accessible as a device file.  This is where xterm writes your input so bash can read it.

Every terminal, including virtual ones, provides basic line editing when it's in cooked (as opposed to raw) mode.  This is handled by kernel code.  It's bash that provides the line editing that you can do with the arrow keys.  (Try running `cat` and typing if you want to see what the basic kernel-provided line editing is like.  Backspace works, and a couple other things as per your stty settings.)

Even though there is a lot of kernel code behind the terminal devices, it would be refered to as terminal-handling code, not as a terminal itself.

Edit: Gilles has convinced me that referring to a tty as a terminal is proper usage.  Terminal Emulators, and interactive programs that run connected to a terminal, are all dependent on the terminal semantics implemented by the kernel.  (Most of this behaviour is standardised by POSIX, and is the same across Linux/*BSD/other Unix.)  A full-screen text editor depends on the behaviour of Unix tty stuff as well as the cursor-movement escape-code handling, and many other features, of the terminal emulator.

However, a physical VT100 with a screen, keyboard, and serial port is an instance of a terminal.  It doesn't require a Unix kernel on the other end of its serial port to be complete.  Something completely different could be sending it escape codes and ASCII text, and receiving the same from it.  It would just be a VT100, though, not a Unix terminal.  A terminal emulator plus the Unix tty semantics make up the full package of a Unix terminal that a program like bash normally runs on.

**Command line** is a style of user interface, where you type something, then press return to make something happen.  It's also used as a shorthand for a command-line shell, like bash or MS-DOS, but you can also say “it's a command line tool” about something like fdisk.  Considering only programs that use a terminal for their UI, the two main families are command line and full-screen text (e.g. an editor like vi or `emacs -nw`).

Command line programs that normally run on terminals almost always still work with their input and output redirected to files, but terminal-based full-screen programs like editors or email clients are interactive-only, and wouldn't work.

A **shell** is a program for starting other programs.  In a Unix context, it's common to mean command-line shell (i.e. Bourne shell or C shell equivalent).  Unix shells can also read their input from files, i.e. shell scripts.  They are full programming languages, with variables, loops, and conditionals, and many programs are written in bash (or with only the `/bin/sh` POSIX shell features, for more portability).  It's also easily possible to write a quick  `for i in *.something; do some_program "$i";done`  in an interactive shell.

Putting it all together, a shell like bash (or whatever program you started by running a shell command) will receive characters from the `/dev/pts/N` terminal device after xterm writes your input into its side of the pseudo-terminal.  If you run `cat`, then hit `^c`, the kernel tty code will act on the `^c` and send a `SIGINT` to the foreground process on that terminal.  (Note the usage of *terminal* in this context to mean the Unix tty, not a terminal emulator or something hooked up to a serial port.)  This happens because the shell puts the terminal into "cooked" mode before starting any program, which means the kernel acts on some control-sequences.  (The tty code still has nothing to do with handling VT100 escape codes, just a few low-ASCII control codes.)  If instead of an xterm, you are using the Linux console text terminal, then the kernel IS doing the VT100 emulation, and handling all that stuff.  Linux can be compiled without virtual console text terminal support, but not without tty support.

**Console** is sometimes used as a synonym for terminal (KDE even has a terminal emulator called Konsole).

As 0xSheepdog points out, it also has another meaning: locally attached human-interaction hardware.

In a kernel context, console has another specific meaning: it's the terminal where boot messages are written.  This can be a serial port.  Normally, of course, it's the text console implemented by the kernel on top of the drivers for graphics hardware and USB/ps2/AT keyboards.  If you boot Linux with `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8` on the command line, you'll get kernel messages on your screen AND on the serial port.

Linux implements virtual consoles (`/dev/tty1` to *N*).  You can swap which one your physical screen/keyboard are controlling with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*N*</kbd>.  Typical Linux distros create 6, and start `getty` on all of them, so even if you can't or don't want to start X11, you can log in 6 times and flip between a command, a man page, and whatever else, without running a program like screen.  Linux (the kernel) includes a VT100-style terminal emulator to provide a terminal interface through your screen and keyboard on the virtual consoles.

The standard 6 virtual terminals with login prompts is why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> gets you back to your X11 session: the X server grabs the next available virtual console.  (The X server opens `/dev/input/...` directly, rather than getting your keypresses from `/dev/tty7`, though.)

So "swap to a text console" means to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and use that terminal.  Back when computers were slow and didn't have much RAM, some people spent much of their time on the text consoles, since they were fast, you could set a nice font, and even change the terminal size to have smaller characters, but have more on screen at once.  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> swap to prev/next console.  (X11 disables this for its console, of course, leaving only the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*N*</kbd> combo.)

So *console* is the only one of these terms that doesn't have a single well-defined technical meaning.  It has a couple different ones.  (Depending on how you feel about terminal proper vs. terminal plus tty handling, you could say that terminal also has multiple meanings.)

Comment: *Console* meaning the “main” physical terminal isn't only in a kernel context. It's the same [meaning](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_382) in [`/dev/console`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap10.html#tag_10_01). *Console* isn't particularly ambiguous — although it's occasionally used in the more general sense of *terminal*, that's pretty rare (rarer than *terminal* being used to specifically mean a console).

Comment: right, yes, echo foo | sudo tee /dev/console > /dev/null  will print on the screen, if your current VT is in text mode (including framebuffer console, not just literally VGA textmode).  If you booted with the console on a serial port, I think it would go there.  You could say that /dev/console it the device file for whatever the kernel is treating as the system console.  Nothing else in the system needs to have a notion of there being a console tty at all (except for boot-recovery stuff that starts a shell on the console TTY if the system fails to boot to multi-user mode.  Usually from initrd)

Comment: The xorg X server (strings /usr/bin/Xorg) doesn't use /dev/console to get hardware access.  It does use /dev/tty0, and /dev/tty%d, and /dev/vc/%d, to set itself up on its own VT.  I'm pretty sure Xorg would still run fine on a PC that booted with the kernel console on a serial port.  And that the text-mode virtual terminals would still work.  The more I consider this, the more I'm leaning towards viewing console in a kernel context as just a special terminal, selected at boot time.  (Linux can actually output its console messages on multiple terminals at once, if you ask it to.)

Answer (score 8):

I think that back in the early days of time-sharing computers, every user had a terminal (when they could get one!), but only the system operators had a console. The console could be used for tasks like rebooting the machine or getting system diagnostics that weren't possible from user terminals. The console was in the machine room, an intrinsic part of the computer, whereas the terminals could be remote. The console would also include hardware lights and switches, not just text input and output.

I would say that the command line is an area where a user can type a command, whereas the shell is the program that interprets/obeys that command. The term "shell" is very particular to Unix derivatives; "command-line" is more in the Windows/DOS tradition. The equivalent on mainframes is usually called a "job control language".

Clearly, these original distinctions have become blurred over time as technology changes.

Answer (score 4):

This is a vague topic, because the terms are very ambiguous. I strongly recommend reading the links I've provided throughout this answer, which are also my sources for this answer.

A **[shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29)** is the layer above the kernel:

- It interprets the commands entered by the user, and processes them. The shell has access to the kernel, unlike users. Users can only access the kernel through entering commands using a shell, and by using processes (i.e. running programs). Programs use [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to access kernel functionality. All system calls together form the system API.
- Examples of shells are given in the second terminal definition.

A **[terminal](http://www.linfo.org/terminal_window.html)** has many meanings:

- (1) A **text terminal**. This is the combination of a display monitor and a keyboard. A cable connected the terminal to the computer (often indirectly). It was called a terminal since it was located at the terminal end of this cable. These terminals were usually physically separated from the computer, because back in the days many terminals were connected to a single mainframe/computer, so multiple users could have access to the computer at the same time.
- (2) A **terminal window** a.k.a. **terminal emulator**. In Linux, a terminal window is the emulation of a console, contained in a GUI window. It is the CLI you type your text in, and this input is read by the shell you're using. There are many types of shells (e.g. bash, dash, ksh88) and terminals (e.g. konsole, gnome).
- (3) For an explanation on **pseudo terminals**, view [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79354/145775). It's a pair of two 'device files' used for communication between a process and a terminal emulator.

A **[console](http://www.linfo.org/console.html)** has many meanings:

- (1) an instrument panel containing the controls for a computer.
- (2) A **System console** a.k.a. **computer console**. This is the combination of the display monitor and a keyboard connected to a computer. This is synonymous with what we call a 'text terminal'. Sometimes also other user-input peripherals such as a mouse is part of a console.
- (3) A command-line interface that covers the full screen. This is in contrast with a terminal window, which is a GUI with an X at the right top corner to close it. These are the two display modes for CLI (command-line interfaces) in Unix-like systems. Similarly to a terminal window, the console can run many shells as well.

Often, operating systems allow you to run multiple consoles on a physical console (console definition 2). These are called **virtual consoles** a.k.a. **virtual terminals**, and can be accessed through <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fx</kbd> combinations. For example, if you want to open the 3rd virtual console, you use the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Consoles (definition 3) might appear to you as an anachronism, but experts should be comfortable using them, since there are many OSes that do not support GUI's. Also, if a GUI stops responding, the console may still work.

Answer (score 3):

Trying user-centric short answer:

**command line** - the line where you enter commands. Usually it used to tell that you need to run something in text mode window (command line interface) provided by your operating system.

**shell** - the actual program run by operating system to process stuff you enter into `command line`. Hence the name - user-friendly shell for non-friendly OS core. It provides command prompt, such as `$` or `>`, runs its own commands and apps. You always work through the `shell` program and never operate with console or terminal directly.

**console** - is a window where your text mode programs are running. This window processes key presses, knows it is width and height. Can be fullscreen.

**terminal** - is some device with display for humans that accepts input stream of characters and shows them. There is no feedback to user about height or width (only hacks) or keyboard keypresses - only chars are travelling to it. Terminal processes special sequences in this stream to make things colored, clean up the screen and do other nasty things. Terminals are flaky, because it is easy to mess things if the file you are piping to output contains that special sequences. They are popular in networking and device debug interfaces, because you just need a single stream for sending output and control the output device and you can just `tap` into conversation without the need to initialize or create a window.

**serial console** - is a console that processes input stream like a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Most **terminals** nowadays are strictly speaking *terminal emulators*.
It is a type of *role* in the workings of a UNIX-like system and at the same time the basic interface offered by the systems. In fact everything, including the GUI builds on top of it.
Colloquially "terminal" may also refer to end-points in a computer network with a star-topography.

**Console** refers to the (hardware) interfaces for the terminals. I.e. there are *serial* consoles and nowadays mostly *virtual* ones.
The window colloquially referred to as "console"-window is a shell, connected to a terminal of the system, via a virtual console.

Back in the day when computers were expensive a facility might have had one actual computer and several terminals connecting to it, via serial cables ("serial console"). The OS, operations, etc. were carried out on the physical Computer, input and output happened on the console(s).
You can switch between virtual terminals by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>(through to <kbd>F6</kbd>): a leftover of those times.
Today the concept of "thin clients" goes back in this direction of centralizing massive amounts of resources and providing just enough hardware to provide a state of the art interface at the actual workplace.

**shell** is the "engine" that you see in the terminal. It provides interop with the system itself and adds nice features like auto-complete, variables etc..
It translates back and forth between the actual OS / kernel which uses system calls and you. System calls w/o shell are a bit like coding `assembler` and a shell at least gives you `C`.

**command line** refers to the method of exchanging input and output via a text-window. Strictly speaking the line in which you type is *the* (current) command line. The method in general is more correctly referred to as *command line interface* or CLI.

1. kernel
2. offers terminal
3. terminal is connected via a console
4. console runs shell
5. commands and output are exchanged via command line (interface)

Comment: Command line instructions are not understood by the kernel, but by a shell. The “core framework of instructions that the kernel understands” would be system calls. The “basic UNIX command line interface” is a shell, there's no separation between that and the “nice features”. A “terminal-emulator-window” isn't a console.

Comment: @Gilles adjusted. Obviously confused some things myself there.