# Launchers for several different workspaces?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Good evening. Please help me with the meanings of these 4 commands:

- /bin/sh
- /bin/dash
- /bin/bash
- /bin/nbash

**Google Translate of:**

Bonsoir svp aide moi avec la signification de ces 4 commendes:

- /bin/sh
- /bin/dash
- /bin/bash
- /bin/nbash

Comment: English, please!

Answer (score 0):

Bash is the [Bourne Again Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-Bash_003f.html), and Dash is the [Debian Almquist Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell). The shells are used to interact with the system via commands. See [What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/506510/158442) and [What is a shell?](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-a-shell_003f.html)

`/bin/sh` is a shell whose behaviour is expected to conform to [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html). It allows people to write scripts that can work across a variety of Unix-like systems without worrying about whether the system has ksh or bash or zsh or something else. Originally, `/bin/sh` was the [Bourne Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), but nowadays, practically no one provides the Bourne Shell as `/bin/sh`. Everyone symlinks `/bin/sh` to another shell, often `/bin/bash` on Linux systems. Debian and descendants (including Ubuntu) are the biggest exception - they symlink `/bin/sh` to `/bin/dash`.

There is no `/bin/nbash`, but perhaps you meant `/bin/rbash`. `rbash` runs `bash` with restrictions. Quoting [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html):

> [The] following are disallowed or not performed:
>
> - Changing directories with the `cd` builtin.
> - Setting or unsetting the values of the `SHELL`, `PATH`, `ENV`, or `BASH_ENV` variables.
> - Specifying command names containing slashes.
> - Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the `.` builtin command.
> - Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the `-p` option to the `hash` builtin command.
> - Importing function definitions from the shell environment at startup.
> - Parsing the value of `SHELLOPTS` from the shell environment at startup.
> - Redirecting output using the ‘`>`’, ‘`>|`’, ‘`<>`’, ‘`>&`’, ‘`&>`’, and ‘`>>`’ redirection operators.
> - Using the `exec` builtin to replace the shell with another command.
> - Adding or deleting builtin commands with the `-f` and `-d` options to the `enable` builtin.
> - Using the `enable` builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins.
> - Specifying the `-p` option to the `command` builtin.
> - Turning off restricted mode with ‘`set +r`’ or ‘`set +o restricted`’.
>
> These restrictions are enforced after any startup files are read.

Comment: merci pour votre aide