# Git Terminal in Linux

Tags: git

I'm new in Ubuntu or Linux in general. I just switched from Windows to Linux to keep my work here. Actually working as web developer.

I use Git commands a lot, and when I clone a repo, I don't get that good looking terminal like I had with Git Bash on Windows, like giving me branch name when I'm inside a folder, some autosuggestions/autocomplete...

I'm looking for another terminal program, like hyperTerminal or the one that comes with Manjaro.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you want to change the $PS1 to something more colorful; why don't you just change it?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt  (*assuming that' s your issue*)

Comment: Thanks for your replies but I'm not looking only for changing colors in Ubuntu Terminal or just add the branch name.(I edited my post to be more specific)

Comment: @JuniorDev I think you ought to read https://askubuntu.com/q/506510/158442 first

Comment: Everyone has their own personal preferences, but if you don't like the built-in git capabilities of your web development IDEs, then there's a raft of Git clients for Linux that might appeal to you: https://ubuntupit.com/best-git-clients-for-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
https://github.com/HenzelMoras/myconfig

usding zsh shell with .zshrc which allows autocompletiion, suggestion extra using oh-my-zsh https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh

install if not present

```sh
sudo apt install zsh
```

change default shell to zsh

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

install oh-my-zsh

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

then edit .zshrc file u can refer my config file settings

```
nvim ~/.zshrc
```

source the file

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

tmux for multiple split panels and windows

```
sudo apt install tmux
```

then Neovim 0.5 to to make terminal editor just like an idle

u can refer my dot files for examples

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers online & in various stack-exchange forums that show custom functions (`foo() { call git and get info }` ) and then integrating into `PS1` ...but so many people have done it, that now much of this has been added to git.

First, install git (of course) & bash-completion (`sudo apt install git bash-completion`) and add to your prompt, using the git documentation (I believe bash completion may be a prerequisite, but even if not, it's really useful):

- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/add-bash-auto-completion-in-ubuntu-linux/
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Bash

Comment: @mondotofu ??? the question is about git command line formatting; your comment has nothing to do with the question & even less to do with my answer.